# Телеграм бот на питоне - выполнение скрипта при нажатии кнопки

Tags: python, telegram-bot

День добрый. пишу по интернету телеграм бот на питоне, сейчас код таков:

```
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.utils import executor
from aiogram.utils.markdown import text
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher

import keys as kb


bot = Bot(token='token')
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


##




@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'btn1')
async def process_callback_btn1(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id)
    await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, 'Управление светом', reply_markup=kb.light_full)
```

Сейчас при нажатии этой инлайн кнопки у меня появляется ещё одна инлайн клава, но мне нужно чтобы при нажатии этой кнопки - выполнялась команда питона - которая выполнит определённый скрипт, потом сохранит данные и чтобы я мог получить данные с лога в виде вывода или переменной. Надеюсь понятно объяснил, извините - я просто не шарю.

Comment: То есть нужно просто выполнить команду? Можно же объявить глобальную переменную, и получить доступ к ней из функции? Или я неправильно понял?

Comment: Скажи пожалуйста, а как здесь можно это реализовать? ну да - команду, допустим выполнить скрипт /blabla/bla.py который создаст текстовый файл с цифрами - допустим "100" и чтобы данные с этого файла можно было взять. логика такова: нажимаю кнопку в телеграме, на сервере выполняется скрипт /blabla/bla.py который создаст /bla/bla.txt в котором будут цифры "100" (например) и отправит их в сообщении в чат телеграма.

Answer (score 0):

Для этого ты можешь в боте использовать встроенный модуль OS и SYS.

```
import os
import sys
os.system("python файл.py")
```